# Angular reactive form validation.I cant validate the selection field with the numbers.It always writes me some error and i can't submit

Tags: angular

I cant validate the numbers in the selection field with Formcontrol validators.it does not leave me to submit in turn i've chosen some.It's important to get all values in one formgroup, because it has to be send to the backend.

```
  profileForm: FormGroup;

constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {

}
```

Here is the form validation:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.profileForm =  this.fb.group({
      email: new FormControl(this.emailInput, [Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$')]),
      kod: new FormControl(this.nameInput, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(8),
      ]),
      date: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      hour: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)?$/)]),
      minute: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
    });

  }

  get kod() {
    return this.profileForm.get('kod')
  }
  get email() {
    return this.profileForm.get('email')
  }
  get date() {
    return this.profileForm.get('date')
  }
  get hour() {
    return this.profileForm.get('hour')
  }
  get minute() {
    return this.profileForm.get('minute')
  }
}
```

html

```
<div id="content">
  <h1>Kódfeltöltés</h1>
  <form [formGroup]="profileForm" #login="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```

here is the problem :

```
      <label for="dropdownOption1">Óra:</label>
      <select  formControlName="hour"required name="dropdownOption" id="dropdownOption1" name="hour">
        <option value="" disabled selected></option>
        <option required *ngFor='let i of counter(24) ;let in = index' [ngValue]="i">{{in}}</option>
      </select>
    </span>
    <div [ngStyle]="{'color':'red'}" *ngIf="hour!.errors?.['required']">
      Az óra kötelező
    </div>
    <span>
      <label for="dropdownOption2">Perc:</label>
      <select formControlName="minute" required name="dropdownOption" id="dropdownOption2" name="mins" >
        <!-- <option  value="" disabled selected></option> -->
        <option  required *ngFor='let i of counter(60) ;let in = index' [ngValue]="i">{{in}}</option>
      </select>
    </span>
    <div [ngStyle]="{'color':'red'}" *ngIf="minute!.errors?.['required']">
      A perc kötelező
    </div>
    <button (click)="sendMessage()" [disabled]="!profileForm.valid" type="submit" mat-button
      color="primary">Kódfeltöltés</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay @RebekaSüveges, Could you remove this: [disabled]="!profileForm.valid"

- put a breakpoint in your browser debugger into sendMessage function to see the form values.
  And let see if it's hour or minute that is INVALID.

I think hour will be INVALID because your regex.
Solution 1 :
--- remove your regex validator because you fill the select option so you don't need validators..

Solution 2 :
Fix this regex to accept numbers as string